# What are my custom reply-to addresses not used in MC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I have created a Sender Profile with custom reply-to name/address fields defined. When doing a send preview you can clearly see the values differ from the From Name/Address fields however when I receive the email and try to respond, it responds to the From Address.

It should be noted I've disabled RMM, by unchecking "Has DNS been updated".

Can anyone explain why my email sends don't have the correct reply-to addresses?

**Edit: Added screenshots to show what settings have been used, redacted part of the domain and sender names.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a screenshot of the Sender Profile and RMM?

Comment: Added some screenshots to original post

Comment: Why did you disable RMM? The custom settings can't be used with the Enterprise setup done first, so I would imagine disabling it would stop the customs settings from working.

Comment: We didn’t want to use RMM, ie fuzzy addresses for reply to addresses. The only way we could disable this behaviour was to disable RMM. Using custom reply to addresses is basic email functionality so I would guess it doesn’t need MC’s RMM feature to function.

Comment: @AnonWonderer cc

Comment: I'll let someone else confirm, but I think your only option is to use direct forwards then. The 'Custom RMM Settings' are just used to override certain properties of the Enterprise RMM, I don't believe it can act as a replacement for it.

Comment: I am pretty sure with RMM not being used, you can only set the replyto email info in  `Email Studio -> Admin -> Account Settings -> Edit` Via the 'Email Reply Address' and 'Email Display Name' under General Settings. I do not believe you can set it per email without RMM. I would discuss with SFMC support to see if they have any work around, but I do not know of any.

Comment: So it there no way to set custom reply email addresses that don’t use fuzzy addresses through RMM?

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to see the bottom part of your Sender Profile, but let's give it a shot - try configuring the bottom part of the Sender Profile in the following way:

[image]

Comment: Apologies, so that part there has `hello@company.uk` instead of `hello@mailer.company.uk` in the "Used specified information" address field (and 'use custom settings below' checked of course) but my Sender From address is used when I respond in my email application (to a test send).